# Make webserver reload the system wide environment variables

Tags: login, environment-variables, webserver, etc, lighttpd

I made changes on the `/etc/environment` file and want the webserver user `www-data` to benefit from them without rebooting the server.

It seems that, in order to reload the `/etc/environment` file, [I only need to *login*¹](https://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting).

Therefore, I'm trying to make the `www-data` user proceed to the *login*, but didn't find anything relevant.

I'm using `lighttpd` webserver.

How can I make the webserver (and it's user) aware of the changes in `/etc/environment` without a reboot?

Comment: System users don't log in the way human users do. What init system are you using (sysvinit, upstart, systemd, …)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure I fully understood what you exactly trying to do here. Are you saying that you allow webserver and its user to login via shell?

However, beside the mysterious usage that you want to do with lighttpd, if you want to apply the env setting and make webserver aware of the envs, all you need to do is to bounce the lighttpd. You don't have to reboot the server for this but just web application.

Comment: what do you mean "bounce"? fyi: a `service lighttpd restart` doesn't seam reload the the `/etc/environment`